# CSS centering with 100% width

Tags: css, width, center

I'm trying to center all the content of a page so that when you adjust the size of the browser, the content moves along with the adjustment. I use the CSS code:

```
margin: 0px auto;
width: 670px;
```

However, I want a colored header to cover 100% of the width, while the text within the header adjusts with the rest of the page. How do I simultaneously do these two things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this, of course you should use full spec html and linked css style sheets...

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="height:120px; background-color:#FF0000;">
    <div style="background-color:#FFFF00; width:670px; margin:0 auto;">
        My page title
    </div>
</div>
<div style="background-color:#00FFFF; width:670px; margin:0 auto;">
    My page content
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a page with a header that stretches the full width of the screen, but has content that is limited to the 670px area.

http://jsfiddle.net/CaUD3/

Hope that gets you started.

Bob

Comment: This breaks if you shrink your viewport width below 670px.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have a comma between the values used in the `margin` property.  Instead, it should appear as follows:

```
margin: 0px auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Nest the text in a paragraph within the container the text is currently in, and set the paragraph's style to what you need it to be, while setting the container's style to be 100% width.

Answer (score 0):

Use `margin-left:20%;
     margin-right:20%`
That should centre your content.

If u want a readymade solution. take a look at [Matthew taylor's Layouts](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/ultimate-multi-column-liquid-layouts-em-and-pixel-widths)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to nest some divs...

```
body{
margin: 0px;
text-align: center;
}

div#container{
text-align: left;
background-color: #ffffff;
width: 670px;
margin: 0px auto;   
}
```

That should center your div#container and you can put your content within that container.

EDIT:  The above will just center your page container.  I missed the header part.  Here is that...

```
body{
margin: 0px;
text-align: center;
}

div#header-container{
height: 200px;
background-color: #999999;
}

div#header{
text-align: left;
background-color: #999999;
width: 670px;
height: 200px;
margin: 0px auto;   
}

div#content{
text-align: left;
background-color: #ffffff;
width: 670px;
margin: 0px auto;   
}


<html>
<body>
<div id="header-container">
     <div id="header">Page Title and the such...</div>
</div>
<div id="content">
Some Page Content
</div>
</body>
</html>
```